# Wicket: Replacing Panels with fadeIn and fadeOut (WiQuery, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, wicket, fadein, fadeout, replacewith

I have a DIV and want to show a listItem-Panel and if i click on the DIV the listItem-Panel should be replaces by a listItemDetail-Panel. For this reason, the DIV contains a Child-DIV with Wicket:ID=curPanel.

```
    div.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {
        @Override
        protected IAjaxCallDecorator getAjaxCallDecorator() {
            return new AjaxCallDecorator() {

                @Override
                public CharSequence decorateScript(final CharSequence script) {
                    return String.format("$('#%s').fadeOut(1000, function(){ %s });", div.getMarkupId(), script);
                }

            };
        }

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            final Panel curPanel = (Panel) div.get("curPanel");

            if (curPanel.getClass().equals(listItemDetailPanel.class)) {
                curPanel.replaceWith(listItemPanel);
            } else {
                curPanel.replaceWith(listItemDetailPanel);
            }

            target.addComponent(div);
            target.appendJavascript("new Effect.FadIn($('" + div.getMarkupId() + "'))");
        }
    });
```

I use the AjaxCallDecorator to fadeOut the DIV (which contains the listItemPanel or listItemDetailPanel). After that, the Panel will be replaced by the other one and then the DIV should appear via fadeIn.

But this is the Problem! What should I do, to fadeIn the DIV after the Ajax-Replacement?

You can see the target.appendJavascript() call, but this did not work!

I need a solution for Wicket/WiQuery. I know the solution for jQuery and i want to adopt them.

Thx Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Use target.prependJavaScript(). This is executed *before* the DOM replacement. While #appendJavaScript() is *after*.

Additionally with 1.5-RC5 Wicket supports PubSub in its Javascript and it publishes an event for "/dom/node/removing" and "/dom/node/added" channels respectively before and after the DOM replacement.

You can subscribe with (use IHeaderResponse to add this Javascript to your page):
Wicket.Event.subscribe(channelName);

where 'channelName' is either fully qualified name as the ones above or '*' which will listen for all channels.